# Follow link with no click event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, screen-scraping

I've made a very simple web scraper for a few projects where I've mainly been navigating using the click function. Several times I've run into the `<a>` element with no event handler, and I hit a dead end using that. I'm wondering how to follow a link like this using Javascript?

As an example let's say I want to follow the Reddit link here:

```
<a class="title may-blank " data-event-action="title" 
href="/r/funny/comments/6i331m/chuck_norris_pinned_by_my_dad/"
tabindex="1" data-href-url="/r/funny/comments/6i331m/chuck_norris_pinned_by_my_dad/" 
data-inbound-url="/r/funny/comments/6i331m/chuck_norris_pinned_by_my_dad/?utm_content=title&amp;utm_medium=hot&amp;utm_source=reddit&amp;utm_name=frontpage" rel="">
Chuck Norris pinned by my dad.</a>
```

Any help is appreciated, and if there's a big concept I'm missing and you could point me in the right direction I'd be forever grateful.

Comment: Load the href prepending the location.host  - that is the NORMAL way - you seem to want to use an event handler? Why?- Also  why not use the api: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/ ?

Comment: Not married to the event handler idea, it's just the only way I've done it so far so I will figure out the first method you suggested. And yeah api is the best, my project isn't in reddit I was just messing around in the console on there and asked this question. Thank you @mplungjan

Comment: Note depending on where you do your scarping the href may be fully qualified - also a base href tag may be present to change things